# How to add keybinding to open specific terminal profile in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to add a new keybinging to open specific (e.g. wsl) terminal with the following setting:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+3",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile",
    "args": {
        "profile": "Ubuntu (WSL)"
    },
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

However, that did not work out. I believe it is caused by the wrong setting in the `args`, but what is the correct `args` to pass into?

Comment: It might be `"profileName"` .  I don't get the quickPick anymore with that but it doesn't open the right profile for me for some unknown reason.  Maybe you'll have better luck.

Comment: I have the same problem. "profileName" seems to be the correct argument (because the pop-up doesn't appear anymore) but it still opens the default terminal instead of the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Mark said in the comments, the correct args is `"profileName"` (described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/001fb95c3d53ab7cc2ee2d28298808790290aff6/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalActions.ts#L2298)).

I have a profile configured to open a Python REPL named, well . . . "Python".

The keybinging below is working fine for me:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+p",
        "command":"workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile",
        "args":{
            "profileName":"Python"
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
```